# msal-angularv2.0.4 IE11 not working with promise polyfill

Tags: azure-active-directory, internet-explorer-11, azure-ad-msal, polyfills, msal.js

I believe we have everything mentioned in https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-angular/docs/v2-docs/ie-support.md

We have included a promise polyfill at the top of our index.html:

```
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bluebird/3.3.4/bluebird.min.js" class="pre"></script>
```

However when attempting to run the angular app in IE11 we get: Script 1002: syntax error

We are building the app with ES5, including adding IE11 to browserlist.rc and I have also tried including all core-js polyfills.

Perhaps I am adding the promise polyfill in the wrong place for angular? However I also tried an angular promise polyfill package, which did not work.

Not sure why IE11 is not loading at all, i believe it may be a difference with msal js and msal angular?

Comment: Does your Angular app work in IE 11 without MSAL? Have you referred to [this doc](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-browser/docs/internet-explorer.md) to support IE 11? Which line of code does the error point to? I suggest that you can provide [a minimal code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which can reproduce the issue so that we can have a test and see how to help.

Comment: the app works fine without msal, and the error just points to the msal library. @YuZhou

Comment: Please refer to this [IE 11 sample](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/samples/msal-browser-samples/VanillaJSTestApp2.0/app/ie11-sample). Besides, please check your project detailly according to [this doc](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-browser/docs/internet-explorer.md) to see if you have meet all the demands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone having similar issues:

We were using MSAL-angular v2.0.4 with Angular 6. Having downgraded to MSAL-angular v1.4.0, IE11 works fine.